# Django: 'HttpResponseRedirect(reverse())' redirects to the same page

Tags: django, django-views

`HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('success'))` leading to the same page which requested with URL changed.

**views**

```
def dashboard_tools(request):
    ...
    if request.method == "POST":
        ...
        return render(request, "tools/loading.html", {})
        # return redirect('success')
        # return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('success'))

    return render(request, "tools/dash_tools.html", {'data':all_entries})

def success(request):
    return render(request, "tools/loading.html", {})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'$',tools.views.dashboard_tools,name="tools"),
    url(r'^success/', tools.views.success, name="success"),
]
```

The `return render(request, "tools/loading.html", {})` redirects to correct page but `return redirect('success')` and `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('success'))`fails to do so.

The redirect and HttpResponseRedirect redirects to the same page with url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/success/`

Comment: The parameter passed in the `reverse` function is the `url` name that we give in the `urlpatterns`. So looks like you are passing `success` as the parameter and you are redirected to `success/`. So its correct right.

Comment: Yep, I don't know why this redirecting to the same page.

Comment: If you redirect to `success`, it will take you to `success` : ), i didnt get your question.

Comment: @Ejaz In views if I use 'return redirect('success')' it should redirect me to 'loading.html' when I press submit button in POST but it is not doing that. It just showing the same page that requested it after reloading.

Comment: TypeError at /myPage/slugName/
reverse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'myModel_slug'

Answer (score 0):

Typo error in urls.py, this line

```
url(r'$',tools.views.dashboard_tools,name="tools"),
```

should be changed to

```
url(r'^$',tools.views.dashboard_tools,name="tools"),
```

Now it works.